# How to sort with conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to sort a table by "number" only if the type is A

```
| number | type |
|--------|------|
| 1      |   A  |
| 2      |   B  |
| 3      |   B  |
| 4      |   A  |
| 5      |   A  |
```

the request would give :

```
| number | type |
|--------|------|
| 1      |  A   |
| 4      |  A   |
| 5      |  A   |
| 2      |  B   |
| 3      |  B   |
```

The rows with "A" type are sorted then the "B" rows are listed (no matter the order)

Is it possible to do it without UNION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(number SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'B'),
(4,'A'),
(5,'A');

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY type,CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN number ELSE RAND() END;
+--------+------+
| number | type |
+--------+------+
|      1 | A    |
|      4 | A    |
|      5 | A    |
|      3 | B    |
|      2 | B    |
+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that what I wase lokking for

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY type, number` will work:

```
SELECT number, type
FROM Tablename
ORDER BY type, number
```

[**Demo on SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbba4c/1)

Note: `ORDER BY type`, here by default it will ordering the `type` values by the ascending order. It is equal to `ORDER BY type ASC`. As per your need, you may use `DESC` or `ASC`.

Comment: thanks but I wase looking for the CASE witch I ignored the existance !

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement can help.

For "B" rows 'no matter the order'. Does that mean original order has to be retained? In that case following query can help.

```
select * from TableName 
order by type, CASE WHEN type='A' THEN number ELSE 0 END
```

If original order need not be retained, then `ELSE RAND()` as answered by Strawberry is good.

Comment: Yeah, not quite sure what this adds to the discussion

Comment: @Strawberry As per the question - While listing "B" rows the order does not matter. Another interpretation for the same is to not sort "B" rows and keep the insertion order intact for them. `ELSE RAND()` will randomize the order and give different order for "B" rows every time query is run, while `ELSE 0` will keep it intact. Please use a larger data set to see it in action.